# Escaping an infinite loop without terminating the browser

Tags: javascript, loops

Is there a way to escape a loop like the one below without closing the browser by terminating it process?

**WARNING**: Don't run the code below.  Running this code will throw your browser in an infinite loop of alerts.

```
<html><body onload="while(true)alert('Hello')"></body></html>
```

Comment: Chrome displays a nice "Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs" option if an alert fires twice in succession.

Comment: Opera has a "stop executing scripts on this page" option too.

Comment: Apparently this problem is rocket science to solve. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=61098 I always wondered why these type of popups even exist... T_T

Comment: Opera, in addition to the "stop executing scripts on this page" option, has the alerts only block out the tab's content (all the controls in the browser's chrome continue operating completely normally), instead of the alert() being modal on a window or even /application/ level.

Comment: If you don't have the "alert", I think you are mostly lost, at least in Chrome. Trying `var i = -1; while (i--) { if (false) console.log(i); }` makes the active tab unresponsive and you can't access its contents anymore. If you had a nice, beautiful fully filled textfield with content you just typed in, good luck typing all over again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some browsers will disallow this from happening in the first place.

Whenever this does happens to me, I do my best to do the following key sequence quickly:

```
[ENTER] Ctrl+W
```

Which will escape the loop and close the window/tab, but shouldn't terminate the browser.

**EDIT** I shouldn't say it escapes the loop. It closes the window which prevents that page from executing any more javascript.

Comment: Do you think it's possible "without closing the tab"?

Answer (score 5):

Firebug plug-in for **FireFox**, mentioned in another answer, is one, albeit overly-powerful, option.

A more targeted one is an [AlertCheck](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/13176/) plug-in.

Here's a screenshot of the checkbox it adds to alert dialogs:

[image]

For non-FireFox browsers, there's no generic answer aside from really quick <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> after clicking/ENTER-ing "OK" which is hard to make work (and may not work on Internet Explorer 6 which IIRC doesn't do Ctrl-W).

Comment: Chrome and Opera offer the option to suppress further messages natively without plugins. Safari does not have one as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

On Firefox, install the [Firebug plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/).  Among many other useful features, it allows you to debug javascript code.